# How to prepare zoo object with mutiple columns for ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make plots of multiple columns of a zoo object. For example,

```
 df <- zoo(data.frame(A = c(2.3, 4.4, 5.2),
                      B = c(5.5, 1.7, 4.4),
                      C = c(2.5, 7.7, 3.3)),
                      order.by = c(as.Date("2010-10-1"),
                                   as.Date("2010-10-5"),
                                   as.Date("2010-10-7")))
```

which gives:

```
              A   B   C
 2010-10-01 2.3 5.5 2.5
 2010-10-05 4.4 1.7 7.7
 2010-10-07 5.2 4.4 3.3
```

One ugly way to convert the zoo object and create the long data form required by ggplot is:

```
 var.vec <- NULL
 val.vec <- NULL
 num.rows <- nrow(df)
 for(i in 1:ncol(df))
 {
   v <- rep(colnames(df)[i], num.rows)
   var.vec <- c(var.vec, v)
   val.vec <- c(val.vec, df[, i])
 }
 df1 <- data.frame(x = time(new.ticker.prices),
                  val = val.vec,
                  variable = var.vec,
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

and the ggplot plot statement:

```
 ggplot(data = df1, aes(x=x, y=val)) + geom_line(aes(colour=variable))
```

This works.

[image: Desired Image]

In an attempt to use a more elegant solution, I have tried converting df to a data frame object and using 'melt' from the 'reshape2' package, but I can't get it to work.

Is there a more elegant way of plotting the columns of zoo object df using ggplot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `zoo` package provides the function `autoplot.zoo`. Try this

```
library(zoo)
autoplot.zoo(df, facets = NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: Ooops. Yes, that works! Was not aware of this function.

Comment: No? Looks like the plot in your question.